# How to echo or include php string in json files

Tags: php, json

I want to echo a php string pulled from database in json object.
Please I want to find out if it is doable if yes where am I getting it wrong?
Here are the codes:
The rest works perfectly.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

(function() {
   <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE subject='SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type='challenge'";
     $results = $pdo->query($sql);
     $results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     while($rows = $results->fetch()){
     ?>

    var questions = [{
        question: "<?php echo $rows['text'];?>",
        choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
        correctAnswer: 2
        }, 
  <?php 
    }
  ?>
    }];
```

Comment: You want output in Json format ? and also let me know expected output.

Comment: Yes I want to output in json format. But I want the questions to be pulled from a database. Using php

Comment: Take a look at the output you get. `var questions = [{...` inside the PHP loop isn't working. You are declaring `questions` every time, overwriting the previous one.

Comment: `var questions = …` inside a loop is not the right way to go about this - you will end up with multiple of those statements in the result, so only the last one will “count”. Plus, you are outputting `var questions = [` inside the loop, but the closing `]` only once after - makes no sense either. You should collect all your data in an array/object data structure first, and then use `json_encode` one time after the loop, to write that out to assign to a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

For json format you should use `json_encode`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE subject='SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type='challenge'";
$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($rows = $results->fetch()){
    $q = $rows['text'];
    $result[] = array(
        "question" => $q,
        "choices" => [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
        "correctAnswer" => 2
    ); 
}
$arrRecord['data']['success'] = $result;
echo json_encode($arrRecord);
```